# Is possibile to use the same view controller to show different content for each?

Tags: ios, swift, viewcontroller

I explain my question: in my iOS app, written in Swift, I have a mapview, using mkmapkit, where i added my mkpoint annotations, seven in total. When i tap on each annotation callout, it opens a new view controller using `performSegueWithIdentifier`.
My question is: Do I need to use seven different view controllers, one for each annotation callout tap, or can I use just one view controller?  Because the view controller design must be the same for all annotation callout taps, but with different content data for each one.

Sorry for my bad english. I hope to figure out to this problem

Comment: use only one viewcontroller , you can pass just tag for annotation. according to tag you can set data "or" pass data along navigating

Comment: Use BOOL to determine what to use, for eg: showKit

Answer (score 3):

When you perform the segue via `performSegueWithIdentifier`, `prepareForSegue` is called. Override this method to pass data to the destination ViewController:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "mySegueIdentifier" {
        let destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController as MyDestinationViewController

        // pass data to destinationViewController
        destinationViewController.myProperty = ...
    }
}
```

Comment: You mean prepareForSegue of the view controller where is the map? Or the prepareForSegue of the view controller where I want to display my information for each annotation?

Comment: The calling view controller. In this function, the seque is *prepared* before it gets executed.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you should use only one ViewController. You just need to pass data from your `MapViewController` into `ViewController` through `performSegue`. And display it.

This pattern called Master-Detail and you can find more here:
[An iOS 8 Swift Split View Master-Detail Example](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_iOS_8_Swift_Split_View_Master-Detail_Example)

Answer (score 0):

Use prepareForSegue to pass individual information to the same view.

Comment: My view controller must show only an image and a text view,  differents for each annotation.

Comment: as in Zisoft's example, pass the selected image and text through using destinationViewController.myimage = imageSelected.